# Spring MVC REST nohandler error

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

Im new to spring MVC and REST.. I'm having an issue with a simple test controller I've put together from example I've found here and from the spring docs..

When I hit the url http://localhost:8080/test-api/user/14 I get the error below
Im getting the error:

```
Sep 23, 2015 11:26:55 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound  noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/test-api/user/14] in DispatcherServlet with name 'testapi'
```

Im using xml to config.. Im not ready to move to java config.

web.xml
        Spring Web MVC Application

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springtest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springtest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/testapi-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

testapi-servlet.xml - only contains the component scan and annotation driven elements

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.springtest.testapi" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

SpringTest.java

```
 package com.springtest.testapi.api;
 @RestController
 public class SpringTest {
    @RequestMapping(value="/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getUser(@PathVariable int id) {
    User u = new User(id,"Test","Me");
    return u;
}
```

What handler should I be defining.. None of the examples or docs state that a handler needs to be defined..

Answer (score 0):

Remove the contextConfigLocation.

Replace the following:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springtest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test-api</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Make sure your xml file is test-api-servlet.xml and not testapi-servlet.xml

Comment: Thank for looking at this.. it ended up being a typo on my part. I posted an answer..

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. I mispelled the package in the component scan. The sample code I have was edited so It didn't fully represent what I had and was actually correct.